# Mailkit Fetch "Unexpected token in IMAP response: [qstring: "Multipart message"]"

Tags: imap, mailkit, mimekit

I'm getting an **ImapProtocolException** with a message:

```
"Unexpected token in IMAP response: [qstring: "Multipart message"]" when issuing  zInbox.Fetch(uids, MailKit.MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId Or MailKit.MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure Or MailKit.MessageSummaryItems.Envelope)
```

But on the other hand if I use **GetMessage(uids)** all goes fine, no error.

Here is **ProtocolLogger** from **Fetch** (you can notice no Fetch Completed message):

```
C: A00000790 UID FETCH 97824 (UID ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE)
S: * 24320 FETCH (UID 97824 ENVELOPE ("Mon, 26 Oct 2015 16:48:44    +0000" "NFe" ((NIL NIL "fatsc" "makrocentral.com.br")) NIL NIL ((NIL NIL "fiscal" "generale.ind.br")) NIL NIL NIL "<20151026164845.43268801F3AD@mail-smtp08-mia.tpn.terra.com>") BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL "Message text" "Quoted-printable" 227 8 NIL ("inline" NIL) NIL NIL)("application" "octet-stream" ("name" "42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.xml") NIL "Attached file: 42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.xml" "Base64" 11086 NIL ("attachment" ("filename" "42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.xml")) NIL NIL)("application" "pdf" ("name" "42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.pdf") NIL "Attached file: 42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.pdf" "Base64" 50364 NIL ("attachment" ("filename" "42151000460986000506550040000387401000387404-nfe.pdf")) NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "017AC96C_005ED075_Synapse_boundary") "Multipart message" NIL))
```

When using **GetMessage(uids)**, Protocologger give me an interesting info:

```
S: X-mailer: Synapse - Pascal TCP/IP library by Lukas Gebauer
```

I already have problems with this mailer when using another library.

As I understand **"Fetch"** belongs to **MailKit** and **"GetMessage"** belongs to **MimeKit**.

So, is there any work-around to proceed with **Fetch** instead of use **GetMessage**?
Loop through ~1500 mails and download each one just to get attachments names take a very long time?

Does anybody here had a similar problems with mailer like this one **"Synapse - Pascal TCP/IP library by Lukas Gebauer"**?

---

So I think now have some more info and questions. Since started this thread I'm dealing with BODYSTRUCTURE and not so much clear (at least to me) RFC 3501.
I have back to talk about "Synapse" again, here is string from Log, the that give me Unexpected Token.

```
S: * 22300 FETCH (UID 32388 ENVELOPE ("Thu, 6 Sep 2018 13:19:10 -0300" "Zebra - XML sent" (("Zebra" NIL "invoice" "zebra.com")) NIL NIL ((NIL NIL "payments" "cat.com")) ((NIL NIL "invoice" "zebra.com") (NIL NIL "mary" "zebra.com")(NIL NIL "igor" "zebra.com")) NIL NIL "<20180906161753.3F4A774030A@proxy.tiger.com>") BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" ("charset" "UTF-8") NIL "Message text" "Quoted-printable" 209 6 NIL ("inline" NIL) NIL NIL)("text" "xml" ("name" "4441004299066.xml") NIL "4441004299066.xml" "Base64" 10642 137 NIL ("inline" ("filename" "4441004299066.xml")) NIL NIL)("application" "pdf" ("name" "4441004299066.pdf") NIL "4441004299066.pdf" "Base64" 48448 NIL ("inline" ("filename" "4441004299066.pdf")) NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "6624CFB2_17170C36_Synapse_boundary") "Multipart message" NIL))
```

As pointed in comments, the problem is at the end part **"Multipart message" NIL**, on the other hand a BodyStructure that works fine can end with "NIL NIL" or **"NIL pt-br".

So, ok, now the question is. What should be the last 2 fields in BodyStructure string?
In mean time I found this:
1) "Multipart message" is coming from "Content-Description" of message header
2) "pt-br" is coming from "Content-Language" of message header

I totally agree to follow RFC, but looks like the last 2 values are not clear from where they should came from.
I mean Content-Language or Language-Tag? Content-Disposition or Content-Description?

Since Exchanges Server and outlook,office365.com become widely used, to me sounds I have to stay using GetMessage and forget about Fetch.

Comment: jstedfast 
Interesting....
In both cases, using another lib and now using MailKit, IMAP server are Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2013 (used in Office 365).

This happens only with messages made with Synapse in a range of 300k msgs.

Is there any additional info I can give to explore a little more about? If message still there I can try.

Would be good use Fetch, and bypass the expection, as soon it comes connection get lost. So have start all over again.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of [revising a three-year-old related question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33481604/revisions). I'll answer in the new one. Thanks.

Comment: This MailKit commit should work-around this Exchange server bug: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/commit/7b33341bfddedc45a018c00024b204b79c3ec6a1

Comment: That said, I would highly recommend submitting a bug report to the Microsoft Exchange team (and send them a ProtocolLog from MailKit to help them see the issue and probably link them to this Stackoverflow question).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the IMAP server responded with a completely broken response.

According to the IMAP specification, the multipart syntax following the `"mixed"` token should be:

```
body-ext-mpart  = body-fld-param [SP body-fld-dsp [SP body-fld-lang
              [SP body-fld-loc *(SP body-extension)]]]
                ; MUST NOT be returned on non-extensible
                ; "BODY" fetch
body-fld-param  = "(" string SP string *(SP string SP string) ")" / nil
body-fld-dsp    = "(" string SP body-fld-param ")" / nil
body-fld-lang   = nstring / "(" string *(SP string) ")"
body-fld-loc    = nstring
```

but what we got was: `("boundary" "017AC96C_005ED075_Synapse_boundary") "Multipart message" NIL)`

This essentially breaks down into the following types of tokens:

```
body-fld-param [SP] string [SP] nil
```

Notice how `"Multipart message"` is not allowed. What *should* be there is either a `NIL` or something like: `("inline" ("name" "value"))`

In other words, your IMAP server is not speaking grammatically correct IMAP. There's no way that MailKit can understand what your IMAP server is trying to say.

Note: the problem is the IMAP server, not the Synapse Mailer in this case.

Comment: I'd be curious what the MIME looked like that caused the IMAP server to be barf so badly.

Comment: I will try get some more info

Comment: Ok, here I am, back to same issue. I´m doing my best to deal with BODYSTRUCTURE and (at least to me) not clear RFC 3501 rules.

Comment: @jstedfast, added some more info about BODYSTRUCTURE & RFC

Comment: @Max, added some more info