# Syntax error in BODYSTRUCTURE. Unexpected token: [qstring: "Multipart message"]

Tags: imap, mailkit, mimekit

Almost 2 years ago I made this post.
[Mailkit Fetch "Unexpected token in IMAP response: [qstring: "Multipart message"]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481604/mailkit-fetch-unexpected-token-in-imap-response-qstring-multipart-message)

During this time I choose GetMessage instead of Fetch.
Now, I´m testing SignalR, just to show a ProgressBar during Check Mailbox and revisiting some threads, I decided to change my code to use Fetch instead o GetMessage, the time difference to have all info I need is HUGE.

But, even upgrading Mailkit to latest version, I´m back on same issue, but this time error message changed to Syntax error in BODYSTRUCTURE. Unexpected token: [qstring: "Multipart message"]

In thread I mention, the conclusion was a problem in Mail Server, not on specific message. What I agree.

Now I sure it is a problem with outlook.office365.com
Here is the log part where Fetch fire exception

S: * 56961 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Fri, 22 Sep 2017 14:05:47 +0000" "=?iso-8859-1?Q?Not_Fara_0000276_s=E9rie_1___-_Ped_int_0032?= =?iso-8859-1?Q?3__Ped_cli_313?=" ((NIL NIL "workflow" "kermoklast.com")) NIL NIL ((NIL NIL "fiscal" "genera.com") (NIL NIL "nfe" "kermoklast.com") (NIL NIL "kjkilber" "gmail.com") (NIL NIL "ven" "kermoklast.com") (NIL NIL "prod" "kermoklast.com") (NIL NIL "vennac" "kermoklast.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<20170922140643.FF5ED40100B@proxy.email-ssl.com>") BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "html" ("charset" "iso-8859-1") NIL NIL "Quoted-Printable" 7170 95 NIL NIL NIL NI

By the way, yes string above ends with "NI"

Comment: MailKit parses the response as it comes in which is why it ends with "NI" (because a 4K chunk of text read from the server ended with "NI"). The problem is likely *not* the last line of the response, all that can be known is that it is within the last 4K of the response.

Comment: Can I presume/suppose lost connection during Fetch Server response?

Comment: Well, an exception occurred parsing the response so it never finished reading the response. The problem is not a dropped connection.